# Django messagebox

Tags: django, messagebox

I'm looking for a "messagebox" app for django (a simple *facebook-like* messagebox).

I just need:
 - the models part
 - the views part

Does that exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[django-messages](http://code.google.com/p/django-messages/), [django-postman](https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/wiki/Home), their [comparison](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/messaging/).